# building specific angular modules as standalone

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an angular project that compiles to a single angular module that will be hosted in a designated IIS server and dynamically fetched into an angular app and loaded as a lazy module

how do I go about structuring my angular project to do so?

ideally I want the project to compile to the single JS file that is usually generated to the dist folder when a module is imported to a router as a lazy loaded module.

Comment: I don't know why are you doing this, but there is a better way to do lazy loading in angular that is perfect solution for your problem. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: The reason is I want to be able to compile a single project that will fetch a config file with an array of module urls and load them so that each consumer of the project could create their own modules to expand the project for their needs